# How to disable an 'option' from 'lightning:select'

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have this `lightning:select` component:

```
<lightning:select name="theme" aura:id="theme" label="Theme:" onchange="{! c.changeTheme }">
            <option value="StandardSalesforce">Standard Salesforce</option>
            <option value="Halloween">Halloween</option>
            <option value="Bloodthirsty">Bloodthirsty</option>
            <option value="Midnight">Midnight</option>
        </lightning:select>
```

How can I disable one of the `option`s in the onchange controller method ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically reset the values of the lightning:select by giving new set of values in the controller.

You can get more details from this. [lightning:select.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I did a kind-of hacky thing

```
<option disabled="{! v.defaultDisabled }" ... />
```

then in the controller

```
component.set("v.defaultDisabled", true);
```

but maybe there is a different way....

Comment: I am sure if that will not work in modern browsers because the presence of word `disabled` will disable the `option` regardless the value (true or false).

Comment: It works on my machine

Comment: This isn't a great solution because you will need one variable for each option. Depending on context, this might still be useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider generating options in your controller or helper and display them like that in HTML.

This will give you control to disable or select value from the code.

```html
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" access="PRIVATE"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String" access="PRIVATE"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <lightning:select name="theme" label="Theme:" aura:id="theme" value="{!v.selectedValue}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="option">
            <option disabled="{!option.disabled}" value="{!option.id}" selected="{!option.selected}">{!option.label}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
</aura:component>
```

In the controller

```js
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.options', [
            {
                id: 'first',
                label: 'First theme',
                selected: true,
            },
            {
                id: 'second',
                label: 'Second theme',
                disabled: true,
            },
            {
                id: 'third',
                label: 'Third theme',
            },
        ]);
        cmp.set('v.selectedValue', 'first');
    }
});
```